# How to use a POST instead of a GET

Tags: http, post, get

I've been reading a bit about post and get methods in http and I'm a bit confused

from the words themselves it sounds like `GET` is to get something/a resource from somewhere and `POST` is to send something somewhere

so I could do something like:

`axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)` and I have received the list of users. that makes perfect sense

and I could do a `POST` request once a user has submitted my form to a database. easy

the bit that confuses me is when people say to use a `POST` instead of a `GET`. like how would I return the users from the url above using a `POST`? also the verbs sound weird if you are using `POST` to receive data??

also I read that `GET` requests can only take stuff over the url whereas `POST` has a response body. but in my example above with the users I got all the users in an array back to my app using `GET` and nothing changed in the url?

can someone help clarify this and explain how to use a POST when doing a GET

Comment: Your basic idea is correct. However: _every_ http request receives an answer and _every_ answer can carry a payload. So technically it is perfectly possible to receive back data on a POST request. And sometimes that indeed does make sense.

Comment: Strictly speaking you also transmit data to the server when doing s GET request: you transfer the request itself which holds information. So the only actual technical difference between GET and POST is the amount of data typically sent.

Comment: ok. but when I do the GET request above compared to the POST I get different things sent back to me in the response? the GET returns me all the users, whereas the POST has just returned me the id: 101 (there are 100 users in the array)

Comment: That is up the the logic processing the request. That logic is not at all specified in the transport layer, it is an implementation specific detail. Think of the two types of requests to the same endpoint as to be processed by separate controllers.

Comment: so as a JS developer I'm just hitting an API end point right but I have no idea what is going to be returned to me until I see what is in the response?

Comment: You _never_ have any idea what is returned, unless you take a look into the documentation of the API. You cannot blindly rely on something you expect.

Comment: ok cool. im getting it a bit more, still confused though as to why you can use a POST to do a GET and why you would ever use a GET if it's deemed unsafe as things are sent back over the url and limited in size? also what does sending over the url mean? I made a GET to get the users and nothing was added to the url? I just got data back into my react app?

Comment: I never wrote that you can "use a POST request to do a GET request". That might be possible on a protocol level, but whether that is possible in a servers implementation is up to exactly that, the servers implementation! Typically you can _not_ interchange the two types. I only wrote that it is possible and sometimes does make sense from the implementations point of view. Apart from that: http get request is not less secure than a post, this is a fairy tale. Security does not depend on hinding something from the first glance.

Comment: And finally about the data you get back: that obviously is _not_ added to the request URL, you miss understood that completely. Instead you receive a response body back for _every_ http request. That body may hold data, be it a response to a get or a post request.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specific endpoint you are accessing. You *shouldn't* use a POST in lieu of a GET request if your goal is simply to read a list of users from the server. Also, if an endpoint is created as only accepting GET requests and you send a POST request then you will get a 405 "Method not allowed" in response. *However*, if the endpoint allows both POST and GET in order to read a list of users from the server then it depends on the use case for this POST method. The reasons can vary from security to specifying (in the body) the format in which you would like the data returned.

Comment: This is wrong. It is what is _typically_ done, but there is no such technical limit. The semantic of the requests is more something like a "best practice".

Comment: OK, the answer has been improved a bit. Though the last sentence again is nonsense.